# Covariant derivative of a metric tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensor-products, tensors, connections

I am studying differential geometry and in definition of a affine connection to be metric I have read:
$$\nabla g=0$$
where $g=g_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j$ and $\nabla g=g_{ij;k}dx^i\otimes dx^j\otimes dx^k$. I don't understand the notation $g_{ij;k}$. I have thinked that it is a compact notation referred to $(\nabla_{\partial_k}g)(\partial_i, \partial_j)$, it is correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your thoughts are right: it is just a compact notation for $(\nabla_{\partial_k}g)(\partial_i,\partial_j)$.

Comment: @Didier Thanks a lot!